# Find Deepest Node in Binary Tree without extra class?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I came across the problem to find the deepest leaf node in a binary tree.

Every solution I've found does something like this:

```
private class DepthNode
{
    int depth;
    Node n;
}

public class BinaryTree
{
    ...

    public Node deepestNode()
    {
        return deepestNode(root, 0).n;
    }

    private DepthNode deepestNode(Node node, int depth)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to do it that doesn't require declaring a new class to circumvent the issue of returning multiple values?

Comment: Can you return any node on the last level or only the deepest rightmost one?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Unspecified, so either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class with two public fields for the node and the depth is the most Java-like way to do things. Alternatives include:

- An `Object[]` with two elements (for the node and the depth), and
- A `HashMap<String, Object>` where the first entry has key `"node"` and whose value is the node, and the second entry has key `"depth"` and whose value is an `Integer` representing the depth.

A separate class is the most idiomatic though, for Java. Other ways don't have the class, but look a little odd for Java. For example, Python and JavaScript don't need the extra class; neither do most languages, I would guess. Java just insists on names -- and classes -- an awful lot.

Answer (score 1):

In update to my previous answer, it turns out you can do this in one pass. Whenever you find a node without children, keep a pointer to it when the current depth passes the max depth found so far.

```
Node deepest_node = null;

void deepestNodeImpl(Node root, int max_depth, int cur_depth) {
  if (!root) return;
  if (!root.left && !root.right) {
    if (cur_depth > max_depth) {
      deepest_node = root;
      max_depth = cur_depth;
    }
    return;
  }
  deepestNodeImpl(root.left, max_depth, cur_depth + 1);
  deepestNodeImpl(root.right, max_depth, cur_depth + 1);
}

Node deepestNode(Node root) {
  deepestNodeImpl(root, -1, 0);
  return deepest_node;
}
```